# javascript prototype sharing

Tags: javascript, prototype

i want to learn how to use prototype in javascript, i learn that prototype can help me for example sharing functions between many objects

```
var car = function(color, speed) {
    this.color = color;
    this.speed = speed;
}
car.prototype.doors = 4;
var honda = new car('black', 'beep');
var kea = new car('black', 'meep');
document.write(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
honda.doors = 2;
document.write('<br/>');
document.write(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
car.prototype.doors = 4;
document.write('<br/>');
document.write(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
```

I saw a video here : [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLNySpJiiuc)

The guy said that if i update the value of the prototype then the variable will change in all my objectsbut here in my example the value did not change when i changed it.
Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: remove line "honda.doors = 2"  and then see

Answer (score 3):

They will change only for the objects that don't have this property changed explicitly. I changed your code on the last step to set 5 doors:

```
car.prototype.doors = 5;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1hrujL0/
in there you can see that the number of doors changes for the kea object which inherits the value from its prototype, however since we've explicitly changed this property for the honda object, its value is not changed.

Comment: but in the video the guy said that car.prototype.doors will update all doors variable inside each object even though i didn't do that manually on each on of them! (he mean for the explicitly changed one too)

Comment: Basically when you try to access the value of an object, it first checks if the value is set as a property directly to the object. When it is not set, it then checks the prototype of the object. So, when you update a value of prototype, it can only affect the objects that don't have a custom value set for this property.

Comment: Please just check the last minute of the video, he said explicity that both the explicity changed value and the other one that inherit the value from it's constructor's prototype will change the two, i just want to confirm.

Comment: He actually removes the code that sets honda.doors = 4 and then he sets changes the prototype value. What he wanted to say is that you don't have to modify the objects directly to change their values and that you can change the prototype to apply the changes globally, but he didn't mean that the changes will be applied to the objects whose values have been changed explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are reference types, while primitives like Numbers are not. So you'll be using a copy . When you change the value of `honda.doors`, you're not changing it anywhere else. To solve this you can place `car.prototype.doors` as an object, such as `car.prototype.doors = {doors: 4};`

Comment: "When you change the value of honda.doors, you're not changing it anywhere else." I know that but in the video the guy said that car.prototype.doors will update all doors variable inside each object even though i didn't do that manually on each on of them!

Comment: @Seif Eddine Slimene Wrong info , perhaps u should correct him in video comments section

Comment: Please just check the last minute of the video, he said explicity that both the explicity changed value and the other one that inherit the value from it's constructor's prototype will change the two, i just want to confirm

Answer (score 0):

You code made an object similar to this.  If you open chrome dev tools you can verify. When you look for honda.doors it will find 2 before it finds 4.

```
car:{
    color: "black",
    doors: 2,
    speed:"beep",
    __proto__: {
        constructor: function(color, speed),
        doors:4,
        __proto__: {}
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further addition to @Ben answer (They will change only for the objects that don't have this property changed explicitly) This is the same with delete also If you delete the current object property (delete honda.doors;) and then refer to it, It will fetch the prototype property Value. Prototype is called when the current object don't have that property else it always refers to the native property value I hope this helps in understanding of the prototype

Consider this piece of code

```js
var car = function(color, speed) {
    this.color = color;
    this.speed = speed;
}
car.prototype.doors = 4;
var honda = new car('black', 'beep');
var kea = new car('black', 'meep');
console.log(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
honda.doors = 2;
console.log('<br/>');
console.log(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
car.prototype.doors = 4;
delete honda.doors;
console.log('<br/>');
console.log(kea.doors+' '+ honda.doors);
```

Comment: Thanks it really helps: